# Need help first first year university homework problem invloving loops

Tags: python-3.x

In the space provided, write a program that uses nested loops to draw the pattern below. You are not allowed to use any of the formatting functions; your solution must use nested loops and must use calls to `print("*",  end="")` and `print("-",  end="")` to  print  characters  to  the screen (without moving to the next line) and calls to print() to move down to the next line.

```
1 **                                                                            
2 *-**                                                                        
3 *--***                                                                      
4 *---****                                                                    
5 *----*****
```

I have no idea where to start with this problem I'm new to programming.

I must use nested loops and use `print("*",  end="")` and `print("-",  end="")`. I can't use formatting functions and I can only go to a new line using print()

```
**
*-**
*--***
*---****
*----*****
```

needs to be printed in terminal

Comment: "I have no idea where to start with this problem"  The answer is not asking a question on Stack Overflow.  Try messing around with the print function in loops as a start...

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain what you need to do.

If you provide an "end" parameter to the print function, you're overriding the default end parameter `"\n"` which is a new line, therefore any print function you would use end="" wont add a new line.

So in theory, you would have a loop with the number of lines you're supposed to print and another loop inside of it to print the * and to print the -

And since this is a university homework, i would suggest checking how loops work in python and trying to come up with a solution yourself.

Comment: Thanks yo, I was able to it, still learning how loops work but I’m pretty sure i’ve gone it foen now